# What threshold generates the accuracy calculated by a SVM classifier in Matlab's libsvm?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, accuracy, libsvm, threshold

When we use SVM to do classification, we usually will use this kind of code:

```
[predict_label,accuracy,decision]=svmpredict(testlabel,testdata,model);
```

We all know the classifier was using probability to make sure if the predict_label is positive or negative, which is according to thresholds. And with each threshold, we can get a group of sensitivity and specificity, thus we can draw an ROC curve.

My question is the accuracy from the output, we always get a specific number, which is also called ACC. So which threshold is this specific number based on?

Answer (score 1):

The reported accuracy is for the default threshold of $0.0$.

Comment: you mean when testdata is labeled with -1 and 1.

Comment: If you are doing two-class classification, LIBSVM will default to renaming your classes 1 and -1 regardless of what they were. Also, the decision values are not bounded by the class labels: they go beyond 1 and -1.